# When renaming files, how do I use keyboard to rename the next file?

Tags: macos, finder

Using Windows, pressing TAB will finish renaming the current file and start renaming the next one in the list. This is the behaviour I'm looking to replicate on macOS.

Enter > Down > Enter would not work as the first Enter would likely alter the file's placement in the list. Assume that batch renaming is not applicable here.

Comment: In scenarios like this, I switch to **Icons** view from any one of the **List** view, **Columns** view or **Cover Flow** view. Doing so keeping the file/folder placement unaltered even after rename. This doesn't completely removes the pain of renaming multiple items, but at least reduces it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will work and the file will retain its position, if the **Finder / View / Arrange By** is set to **None**.

[image: arrangeNone]

Comment: What version of macOS is this? I am currently on Catalina which is the latest non-beta OS at the time of writing and this menu does not contain "None". It is also called "Sort By" instead of "Arrange By".

Answer (score 0):

1 Select a file and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to edit its name.

2a Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> *twice* in order to go to the next file.

2b You may instead of (2a) press <kbd>Tab</kbd> then navigate with arrow keys. Use this if View/Arrange By is set to something other than None.

Comment: This does not result in the requested behaviour unfortunately.